# Given ${a_n}$ be the sequence of non zero integer with Following conditions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let ${a_n}$ be the sequence of non zero integer Satisfying

$1).|a_n|<|a_{n+1}|\;\;\; \forall n$

$2) a_n \;\;\text{divides}\;\; a_{n+1}\;\; \forall n$

$3). \text{Every integer is a divisor of some } a_n$

Then $$\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3}+\frac{1}{a_4}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;.... is$$

$1).$ Absolutely  convergent and its sum is a rational number

$2).$ Absolutely  convergent and its sum is a irrational number

$3).$ Absolutely  convergent and its sum is a positive number

$4).$ None of above

**solution i tried**-The given series is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_n}$$

so as per given condition $1$ by ratio test the given series converges Absolutly $$\left |\frac{ \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}}{\frac{1}{a_n}} \right |=\left | \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} \right |<1$$

and also it is sum of positive series so sum will be positive but,what can we say about its sum is it a rational or irrational ,i try to solve this question by taking different examples but no sequence satisfies all the given **Conditions** ,please provide me a hint

Thank you

Comment: The sequence $a_n=n!$ satisfies all three conditions.

Comment: so the answer is $$1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+.....$$ which will give $e$ so answer is $2$?

Comment: It’s not that simple, because there are other sequences that satisfy the conditions.

Comment: so i can't say that option $2$ is right,can you please give another example which have convergence to a rational point.?

Comment: You can definitely say that $(1)$ is wrong, and it’s not hard to see that $(3)$ is also wrong, but deciding between $(2)$ and $(4)$ is going to take some work.

Comment: No, it is not necessarily a series of positive numbers: $a_n$ could be $-n!$ for each $n$, in which case the sum would be $1-e$ instead of $e-1$.

Comment: So now i have to find a series whose sum is rational with those conditions.

Comment: Or prove that there isn’t one.

Comment: ok i will try to prove this.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott can you please tell me which from above $3$ conditions will play a key role to drive the prove.?

Comment: You caught me after I went to bed, I’m afraid, but @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг has filled in with an excellent answer. Note that the argument in his third bullet point can also be used to show that the series is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 3):

You have already seen that points $1,3$ are false.

You have seen at least one series where the sum is irrational. While this is not immediately suggestive of $2$, you can still see if something goes wrong while assuming the sum is rational.

---

Suppose $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac 1{a_i} = \frac pq$ for some $p,q$ integers, $q > 0$.

- Let $N$ be the any index such that $q$ divides $a_N$ (by assumption, such an index exists). Then $q$ also divides each of $a_{N+1}, a_{N+2}$ etc. because $a_N$ is a divisor of each of these.
- Let $x_N = a_N\left(\frac pq - \sum_{i=1}^N \frac 1{a_i}\right)$. Why is $x_N$ an integer? (Hint : each denominator is a divisor of $a_N$). The previous bullet point tells us that if $x_N$ is an integer, so are $x_{N+1},x_{N+2}$ etc.
- Simultaneously, we have $x_N = \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac{a_N}{a_k}$. We want to show that $|x_{N}| < 1$. Compare with the geometric series here : clearly $\left|\frac{a_N}{a_k}\right| \leq 2^{N-k}$ because of telescoping. Therefore, $|x_N| \leq \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty 2^{N-k} = 1$.
- But how do we rule out $|x_N| = 1$? That is simple : if $|x_N| = 1$, then each $\left|\frac{a_N}{a_k}\right|$ must be $2^{N-k}$, otherwise the inequality will become strict in the previous bullet point. This forces $|a_k| = 2^{k-N}|a_N|$ for every $k \geq N$. Ask yourself : if $p$ is an odd prime , $p>|a_N|$, then can any term of the sequence be a multiple of $p$?
- Thus, we conclude that $|x_N| < 1$ for any $N$.
- Now , consider two consecutive $x_N$ and $x_{N+1}$. Their difference is $\frac{1}{a_i}$,which is non-zero. Therefore, at least one of $x_N$ or $x_{N+1}$ is non-zero. However, it also has magnitude smaller than $1$, contradicting the fact that it is an integer.
- As a result of the contradiction, the sum must be irrational.

Compare with the proof of irrationality of $e$.